# Regex for getting domain and subdomain in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a requirement to correctly get the domain/subdomain based on the current url. this is required in order to correctly fetch the data from database and further call web api with correct parameters.

In perticular, I am facing issues with local and production urls. for ex.

In local, i have

```
http://sample.local.example.com 
http://test.dev.example.com
```

In production, i have

```
http://client.example.com 
http://program.live.example.com
```

i need

```
Subdomain as: sample / test / client / program
Domain as: exmpale
```

So far i tried to use c# with following code to identify the same. It works fine on my local but i am sure this will create an issue on production at some point of time.  Basically, for Subdomain, get the first part and for Domain, get the last part before ''.com''

```
 var host = Request.Url.Host;
 var domains = host.Split('.');
 var subDomain = domains[0];
 string mainDomain = string.Empty;
  #if DEBUG
    mainDomain = domains[2]; 
  #else
    mainDomain = domains[1]; 
  #endif

 return Tuple.Create(mainDomain, subDomain);
```

Comment: so for the subdomain you want only `sample´ ? without the `http://` ? and for the production the value would be `client` ?

Comment: yes... thats correct...

Comment: Try `^https?://(\w+)?\S*\.(\w+)\.\w+$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/80KxB6/1

Comment: @revo: perfect.... works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of a regex, I think Linq should help your here. Try:

```
public static (string, string) GetDomains(Uri url)
{
    var domains = url.Host.Substring(0, url.Host.LastIndexOf(".")).Split('.');
    var subDomain = string.Join("/", domains.Take(domains.Length - 1));
    var mainDomain = domains.Last();
    return (mainDomain, subDomain);
}
```

output for `"http://program.live.example.com"`

```
example
program/live
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KRJIb0)

Comment: marking this as answer because of the fact that it would be easy for the debugging.

Comment: This will only work for top level domains (.com etc). Try it for a UK (.co.uk) website

Comment: @LeeSmith for this I would keep a dictionary of all TLDs (including especially second-level domain i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain) and write a matching based extraction logic to get the domain.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work for you:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(temp, @"http://(\w+)\.?.*\.(\w+).com$");

string subdomain = match.Groups[1].Value;
string domain = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

`http://(\w+)\.` matches 1 or more word characters as group 1 before a dot and after `http://`

`.*` matches zero or more occurences of any character

`\.(\w+).com` matches 1 or more word characters as group 2 before `.com` and after a dot

`$` specifies the end of the string

`\.?` makes the dot optional to catch the case if there is nothing between group 1 and 2  like in `http://client.example.com`

Comment: @patel.milanb glad to hear

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right and you can get the domain name as the second last value in the array.

```
var host = Request.Url.Host;
var domains = host.Split('.');
string subDomain = domains[0].Split('/')[2];
string mainDomain = domains[domains.Length-2];  
return Tuple.Create(mainDomain, subDomain);
```

If you want all the subdomains you can put a loop here.